# Is "Agentur" usable for animation studio

Tags: meaning, word-choice

On scale 0-10, how fitting is "Agentur" (together with some other word) for a company, that creates advertisement movies.

Eg. Werbevideo Agentur or just Video Agentur.

Answer (score 4):

A **Werbeagentur** does much more than just filming for advertisement, they usually do full-service ad campaigning.

What you mean seems more like an **Animationsstudio** or **Animations- und Werbegrafikstudio**.

Answer (score 2):

An agency `(Agentur)` can be understood as a facilitator of services. For example, a press agency publishes material to the media or an artist agency represents the interests of the contracted persons. The services offered by an agency range from planning and conception to implementation.

There are both individual agencies and agency networks. An important part of an agency's work is customer acquisition.

So, `Agentur` is OK for a simple translation but is a bit dusty in context for a company name creating advertisement movies (I'd vote 4 only on your scale of 0-10).

The translation or name depends on the business model too.

> Werbefilmagentur
>
> Werbevideoagentur
>
> Videoserviceagentur

Comment: In general, though, I have to disagree with your claim that "In Germany Agentur is often used for local sub offices of a company e.g. for insurance or a authority". In fact, the generic German term for independent businesses that offer the professional creation and deployment of advertisements *is* "Werbeagentur".

Comment: @Mapper. ... yes! And the use of "Agentur" for things that traditionally have been called "Behörde" or "Amt" for 150 years is just an ill-fated attempt of decorating these with a trendy name. Bulgarians have a nice proverb for this: "to put a bell on a pig".